# Как создать список и как создать массив?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что создает вот это выражение:

```
a = []
```

В отладчик отображается как список. А как создать массив?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под массивом?

Comment: массивов нет в питоне, есть списки

Comment: `[] - список, list - список`

Comment: чем ваш массив должен отличаеться от пайтоновского списка?

Comment: а как в отладчике должен отображаться массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from array import *
my_array = array('i', [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: typecode must be b, B, u, h, H, i, I, l, L, q, Q, f or d